# Jquery - smooth scroll offset

Tags: javascript, jquery, offset, smooth-scrolling

I have the following js but the offset value (-140) doesn't seem to work. It recognizes the offset the jumps to the top of the browser.

Please help :)

```js
// smooth scroll
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Add smooth scrolling to all links
  $("a").on('click', function(event) {

    // Make sure this.hash has a value before overriding default behavior
    if (this.hash !== "") {
      // Prevent default anchor click behavior
      event.preventDefault();

      // Store hash
      var hash = this.hash;

      // Using jQuery's animate() method to add smooth page scroll
      // The optional number (800) specifies the number of milliseconds it takes to scroll to the specified area
      $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(hash).offset().top - 140
      }, 500, function(){
        

        // Add hash (#) to URL when done scrolling (default click behavior)
        window.location.hash = hash;
      });
    } // End if
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="header"> 
   <canvas class="fireworks"></canvas> 
   <h1 class="logo"><a href="../index.html"><img src="images/quantum-logo.svg"></a></h1> 
   <ul class="menu"> 
      <div class="menu__item toggle"><span></span></div> 
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#overview">Overview</a></li> 
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#structre">Structre</a></li> 
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#timing-easing">Timing & Easing</a></li> 
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="#tension-friction">Tension & Friction</a></li> 
   </ul> 
</nav>
```

Comment: Does `console.log($(hash).offset())` display something ? Cause `null - 140 = -140 = 0`. You may have a problem with your selector

Comment: Didn't display anything... It works the first time the function runs. Any click after that the -140 offset is ignored. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, your `$(hash)` probably select nothing. Can you add HTML example to understand what's contained on `this.hash` and what you're trying to select ?

Comment: ok, i've added the html above. thanks!

Comment: Can you post the result (on your console) of `console.log(hash, $(hash))` just after `var hash = this.hash;`

Comment: Did you try to select `<div id="overview">Overview</div>` or `<a href="foo.html#overview"></a>` with `$(hash)` ?? Because `$("#overview")` is looking for a tag with `id="overview"`

Comment: The console is blank.

Comment: Okay, so can you try `console.log(this.hash, $(this.hash))` just after the event `$("a").on('click', function(event) {`

Comment: Your snippet does not reproduce what you are seeing, because there are no elements with ids that match your anchor references. Add a bunch of `<br>`s, then an element with an id of overview, then a bunch more `<br>`s so that we can see the scroll effect. I have the feeling if you remove the `window.location.hash = hash;` line, it will work like you want.

Comment: I removed that line and it works perfectly now!! Thank you for your help!